# Displaying a Category List and Entries in those Categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, contentful

I'm trying to get a list of results to display categorized like this:

Department

- Job
- Job

Department

- Job
- Job

...etc

I'm using http://contentful.com to pull down a selections of jobs that belong to a department and I'm looking to display the information like above.

I'm guessing my view is going to look like:

```
- department.each do |job|
  = job.fields[:departmentTitle]
  - job.department.each do |j|
    = j.fields[:jobTitle]
```

My controller looks like this:

```
def index
  @department = @client.entries('content_type' => '5qQ755rL9Y8oSGayUuEMkE', include: 1)
end
```

That content type is basically saying grab all departments.

My question is, how should I setup that controller and view in order to display the information in that way?

Comment: Please ask a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how you set up your content model different ways of doing this exist.

Assuming you have a department that links to many jobs your approach seems ok.

You probably want to use `@departments` in your controller and access the instance variable `@departments` in your view.

If you have a job linked to a department you have to fetch all the jobs, and then group them on the client side as explained in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/contentful/contentful.rb/issues/45).

If you have enabled `dynamic_entries: :auto` on the client initialisation you can access the data using the created getter methods:
`job.department_title`.

In case you need more guidance I would suggest that you contact the support on the [contentful.com](https://www.contentful.com) website.